# Does new int[] autoboxes to new Integer[]?

Tags: java

When we print new int[]{2} inside main method, We will get hashcode [I@138a55?
Does int array overrides hashcode?
Is it because new int[] auto boxes to be Integer[]?
What's the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: There is no auto(un)boxing of array types. `[I@138a55` is not a hashcode but a value returned by `toString()` method, haschodes are just ints. Default implementation of `toString()` method returns `[I@74a14482` for `int[]` and `[Ljava.lang.Integer;@1540e19d` for `Integer[]`.

Comment: @LutzHorn It is diferent context

Comment: *"Does new int[] autoboxes to new Integer[]?"*--no, why it should?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[I` is the output of `getClass().getName ()` when executed on an `int[]`. On the other hand, for `Integer[]`, you'll get `[Ljava.lang.Integer;` when calling `getClass().getName ()`.

`int[]` arrays are not autoboxed to `Integer[]`.

`[I@138a55` is not the hash code of the array, only the `138a55` part is the hex representation of the hash code of the array.

`int` arrays don't override the default implementation of `Object`'s `hashCode()`.

Comment: Note: the hashCode of an array is a code for the object not a hashCode of the contents of the array.

Comment: wait.. If where is implementation of getClass().getName(); I don't see any calls to this method.. Is it internal implementation of JVM?

Comment: @AskQ The implementation of `Object`'s `toString()` is `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`. The implementation of `getName()` is in the `Class` class. `getClass` is a native method of the `Object` class, so we can't see its implementation.

Comment: if new int[] is not autoboxed to new Integer[] then toString() of Object should not be get called.. I don't understand how Object o=new int[]; woks as Object is not super class of int[]

Comment: @AskQ An array is a sub-class of Object, regardless of whether the element type is primitive or not. Therefore `Object`'s `toString` is called. Object is a super class of int[].

Comment: Heres what I figured out from comments.. thanks Eran, Peter..Step 1: Object o=new int[]; <br/>then step 2: o.toString() gets called which prints combination of getClass().getName () and the hex representation of the hash code of the array.

Comment: also here new int[] is not autoboxed to int Integer[].. which I though before this question.